# Multiple markers error when using Java List

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following code :

```
String[] array = {"a","b","c"};
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(array[0]);
```

I don't know what's wrong with this lines of code can someone tell why i have Multiple markers error.

Thank's for help

**Edit**

Error say on `list.add(array(0))`:

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Syntax error on token ";", @ expected
>     - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after    this token

Comment: the list interface has no method to add all elements of an array at once. You must use the `Arrays.asList()` util.

Comment: This code runs: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/lUfTPb). My guess is, that this code is not inside any block? Which means you can't do `list.add(array[0])` there. Move it to the constructor instead.

Comment: Seems to work. Which java version are you using?

Comment: The error code does not match the actual code, are you using `list.add(array[0])` or `list.add(array(0))`, the first one works, the second one does not.

Comment: @JornVernee it is inside a class and it doesn't work

Comment: @Nilu Java se 8

Comment: Inside a class alone is not good enough, have you tried my suggestion of moving `list.add(array[0]);` to the constructor? Also, please post the whole code.

Comment: @JornVernee you are right

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported ArrayList and List

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the java.util package

```
    String[] array = {"a","b","c"};
    List<String> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    list.add(array[0]);
```

Comment: what makes you think he does not already do that? there is no reason for a fully qualified name, and he already stated he imported everything.